# How to disable on swipe delete animation on iPhone table view row - titanium?

Tags: titanium

I want to disable on swipe delete animation on iPhone table view row - titanium?

Comment: What you mean by 'on swipe delete animation'. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the *editable* property in your TableView as **false**.

```
var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    editable: false
});
```

Docs: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-editable

Answer (score 0):

The animation of the delete button is native and it can not be changed. 
As Rafel Said, you can set the properties [editable](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-editable) and [editing](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-editing) of tableView as false. But this will not allow to delete the row. And if you want to delete row, you can create custom buttons which will help you to delete a particular row.

**NOTE : If any one of the above property is true, the deletion will be possible**